# asp.net mvc calling dropdown ajax request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ok i have a record grid with different records

plus i  have a dropdown as column as well (which ought to go and just save the value i have selected and come back on the same stage , i have to send some id as well) . how to achieve this . form is at the movement submitting in my code.

```
   <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveStatus", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "jobStatusChanged" }))
              {%>
              <%=Html.Hidden("JobFormMain",item.int_JobFormMain) %>
        <%:  Html.DropDownList("SelectedItem", JobHelper.GetSelectStatus(item.int_JobFormMain) as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })%>
        <% } %>

 public ActionResult SaveStatus(int? page,FormCollection form, int id = 0)
    {    
   return View()
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use jquery to bind to the dropdown's change event, and then post the value to your controller action. You can assign a class to the dropdown to make it easy to select with jquery.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("SelectedItem", JobHelper.GetSelectStatus(item.int_JobFormMain) as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "SelectedItemDropDown" })%>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".SelectedItemDropDown").change(function()
        {
            $.post("controller/SaveStatus", { id : $(this).val() });
        }
    }
</script>
```